# ATS (Application Transport Security) Exception Only for XCTests

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

In my XCTests I connect to an http (not https) server. This does not occur in my production app. Is there a way I can only apply this exception:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>echo.jsontest.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

for the tests, and not for the main app?

I've tried putting this in the Info.plist for the tests, but it does build but doesn't provide the exception.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: No I have not...

Comment: If it helps, I discovered that you can use `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` which Apple supposedly will not require justification for. In my case I am using Embassy to run a local web server in my UI Test target, so it resolves the problem for me (my url is http://localhost). It doesn't help your specific scenario but you could consider doing the same (which would also remove your dependency on internet connectivity to pass tests).